# Popup not waiting for response to close

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I open popup in my application.And do some changes and closes it without saving.It displays a confirmation message and popup windows does not closes.

```
var r = confirm("There are some unsaved changes, do you want to quit?");
```

And further execution goes on user confirmation, `Yes or cancel.(Native jquery buttons).`
My need was to have three buttons,`Yes ,No and Cancel`. I did that like this.

```
 var question = "There are some unsaved changes, do you want to quit?";
            confirmation(question).then(function (answer) {
                // var ansbool = Boolean.parse(answer.toString());
                var r = answer.toString();
                alert(r);
                if (r == "true") {
                   .....
                    return true;
                }
                else {   
                   ....                 
                    return false;
                }
            });

function confirmation(question) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $('<div></div>')
        .html(question)
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Confirmation',
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                    defer.resolve("true"); //this text 'true' can be anything. But for this usage, it should be true or false.
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "No": function () {
                    defer.resolve("false"); //this text 'false' can be anything. But for this usage, it should be true or false.
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    return defer.promise();
};
```

It shows me the message having these three buttons.But also closes the main popup window.I want it when user clicks on `Yes ,No ,`then it closes.After clicking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When are you calling `confirmation`?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen please see the second line of my code.  confirmation(question).then(function (answer) {..

Comment: This happens, since your dialog in the second snippet is not really modal. If you're calling the "modal dialog" in an `onbeforeunload` eventhandler, the page's closing process doesn't wait the modal to be executed, instead it terminates the page.

Comment: I think issue is not with the confirmation.It is just that first i have a confirm and now i have a dialog box.Confirm stops the execution until ant button is pressed.But this case is not with dialog.

Comment: @Teemu can you please edit my code or give an example.

Comment: `confirm()` is really executed modal, i.e. it does block the execution of the script untill it's closed, custom dialogs are not. Use `showModalDialog()`, if you need more content to the dialog than you can get in confirm box. However, using any box, you can't directly prevent the page to close, you can only trigger another prompt asking user if he wants to leave the page.

Comment: The native `confirm` blocks execution, like `alert`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I want dialog box to work like confirm.

Comment: @EHS You can't, in JS there's no way to create a `div` which could block the execution of the rest of the script.

Comment: @Teemu so how can I solve my problem.

Comment: @EHS You could use [`showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog), but you can't automatically prevent the page to be closed. It's simply not allowed by browsers due to the security reasons.

Comment: ok thx all..I work on it

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your confirmation call just drops through, it doesn't wait for an answer.  The only way I know of to do this is to place the action inside the confirmation:

```
UI.confirmDialog('Record will be removed...Continue?').done(function () {
            //perform the desired function here
            return false;
        }).fail(function () {
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Can you please edit my code.Because I am not getting and getting confused in this that how I will put these three buttons in UI.ConfirmDialog.

Comment: Leave your confirmation function alone and then:

    confirmation("There are some unsaved changes, do you want to quit?").done(function(answer) {
      if (answer === "true") {return true };
      elseif (answer === "false") { return false };
    }).fail(function() { return false;
    });

Or something like that, play around with the combination until it works.  Main thing is to use the "done" attribute.